# Time complexity in terms of O?

Tags: time, complexity-theory

What is the time complexity when the size of input increases the time diminishes?

Comment: Could you give an example of such algorithm? I can't imagine any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how quickly the time diminishes. For example if doubling the input size halves the runtime, the run time will be in `O(1/n)`.

Basically this isn't any different than the usual case where increasing the input size also increases the run time.

Of course this is strictly theoretical as in practice there can be no algorithm whose runtime keeps decreasing as the input size approaches infinity.

Comment: I have a detect circles in an image case and I found that the larger the radius the faster the time

Comment: @user2012107 Even so, I can guarantee you that your running time will not decrease indefinitely. If it did, it would eventually reach zero (running time can't become arbitrarily small - if it takes one CPU cycle for n=1000, it can't take half a CPU cycle for n=1001). If the running time eventually reaches a constant after decreasing for a while, it's O(1). Also wouldn't your input size be the size of the image, not the radius of the circles? It sounds more like your running time is something like `O(n/r)` where `r` is bounded by `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the limit of the time is as the size approaches infinity; it is an upper bound for "large enough" inputs.